# How to delete the selected random data in std::vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdvector, std

How to delete the selected random data in vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> shuf{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int random = shuf[rand() % shuf.size()];
    std::cout << random; // to get the random data in shu
    std::find(shuf.begin(), shuf.end(), random);
    shuf.erase(random);

    for (int k = 0; k < shuf.size(); k++)
    {
        std::cout << shuf.at(k) << ' ';
        break;
    }
}
```

For example data in `shuf` vector is `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` then the random data for example is `4` so that the `4` will be deleted in vector, so the data in vector will be `shuf{ 1,2,3,5 }`

This is the error I got

```
no matching function for call to 
'find(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, int&)'
```

Comment: You do not use the result of `std::find(shuf.begin(), shuf.end(), random)`.

Comment: Is this the exact code you are trying to run? If yes then you are missing a semicolon after ```std::find(shuf.begin(), shuf.end(), random)```.
Also, ```erase``` takes an ```vector<T>::iterator ``` not an ```int```.

Comment: Erase wants an iterator that find returns, but only erase it if find() didn't return "end" iterator.  (In this case it will always succeed.)  HOWEVER, this approach is not good, since find is a linear algorithm, and you already know the index of the element you want to erase, so you don't have to find it again--just remember the result of rand() % shuf.size(), and call vec.erase(vec.begin() + index);

Answer (score 2):

At this like

```
shuf.erase(random);
```

you are passing a `random` of type `int` to the `std::vector::erase`, and do not make use of the result of `std::find(shuf.begin(), shuf.end(), random);`.

The [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) expect the **valid  iterator** pointing to the element to be removed, not the actual element. Hence, the error.

From cppreference.com, the `std::vector::erase` needs

> **Parameters**
>
> `pos` -   iterator to the element to remove.
> The iterator `pos` must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the `end()` iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferenceable) cannot be used as a value for `pos`.

Therefore, you might want the following:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::find

auto iter = std::find(shuf.begin(), shuf.end(), random);
if (iter != shuf.end())
    shuf.erase(iter);
```

**([See a Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5Yf8466of))**

Note that you need to include `<algorithm>` (also other required) headers for compiler to see the algorithm function `std::find`.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your answer really appreciated but i tried this i encountered same error

Comment: @woofMaranon You need to #include <algorithm> too.

Comment: @JeJo considering the OP's code, do we need that ```if ``` condition?

Comment: @AshutoshAswal No. But once you change the code prior to the check, it shouldn't break the code base as well.

Comment: @JeJo That makes sense.